# Power Bi - No CSS selector was found for image URL using Examples

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

My goal in Power BI (August 2022) is to get the images from this webside:
https://www.eima.it/en/elenco_espositori.php?APP=&RAGSOC=&RAGSOC__1=agro&NAZIONE=&POSIZIONE=&SETTORE=&PRODOTTI=&Ricerca=Search

So I tried to get data from Web and create a table of image URLs by using "Add table using Examples":

[image]

Unfortunatly "No CSS selector was found..."
So I tried the "WaitFor" function in the datasource:

```
= Web.BrowserContents("https://www.eima.it/en/elenco_espositori.php?APP=&RAGSOC=&RAGSOC__1=agro&NAZIONE=&POSIZIONE=&SETTORE=&PRODOTTI=&Ricerca=Search", [WaitFor = [Timeout = #duration(0,0,0,30)]])
```

But even with the longer Timeout the error remains.

As you can see the Companynames are filled automaticaly but the image URLs just wount.

Here are examples for Names and imageURLs form this page:

AGRO+ Srl
https://www.eima.it/images/espositori/loghi/large/4522.jpg

AGROSTAR Srl
https://www.eima.it/images/espositori/loghi/large/584.jpg

OLIVER AGRO S.R.L.
https://www.eima.it/images/espositori/loghi/large/110528.jpg

RI.MA GROUP Srl
https://www.eima.it/images/espositori/loghi/large/1451.jpg

Please let me know if you have any idea on what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all the images are showing even when you navigate to that page. The following code seems to collect everything available though.

[image]

```
let
    Source = Web.BrowserContents("https://www.eima.it/en/elenco_espositori.php?APP=&RAGSOC=&RAGSOC__1=agro&NAZIONE=&POSIZIONE=&SETTORE=&PRODOTTI=&Ricerca=Search"),
    #"Converted to Table" = #table(1, {{Source}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Converted to Table", {{"Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("""ricerca"">", QuoteStyle.None), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Column1"),
    #"Inserted Text After Delimiter" = Table.AddColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Text After Delimiter", each Text.AfterDelimiter([Column1], "<h2>"), type text),
    #"Inserted Text After Delimiter1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Text After Delimiter", "Text After Delimiter.1", each Text.AfterDelimiter([Column1], "ricLogo"">"), type text),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Text After Delimiter1",{"Column1"}),
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Removed Columns",1),
    #"Extracted Text Between Delimiters" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Top Rows", {{"Text After Delimiter", each Text.BetweenDelimiters(_, """>", "</a"), type text}}),
    #"Extracted Text Between Delimiters1" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Extracted Text Between Delimiters", {{"Text After Delimiter.1", each Text.BetweenDelimiters(_, "src=""", """"), type text}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Extracted Text Between Delimiters1",{{"Text After Delimiter", "Title"}, {"Text After Delimiter.1", "Logo URL"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Comment: After I saw your result I tried /images/espositori/loghi/large/4522.jpg instead of the whole image URL and it worked also with "Add Table using Examples" and it worked. How did you come to this aproach?

Comment: I just quickly worked through the html using inspector on the developer tools in the browser. It is far from optimal though.